# Protractor element is found, but element is not visible?

Tags: element, visible

I have following code:

```
<input ng-required="true" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="text" id="txtPlacementName" data-ng-model="appnexusPmpPlacement.name" required="required">
```

I tried to access the element by id and model. The element shows present when

`expect(browser.isElementPresent(element(by.id('txtPlacementName')))).toBe(true);`

but it shows failure.

`expect(element(by.id('txtPlacementName')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);`

Thus not able to any operation like sendKeys() or Clear(), it gives error element not visible.

I have tried to maximize the browser by adding following to conf.js:

```
onPrepare: function() {
      browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    },
```

Comment: Having this issue. Did you figure it out?